# What is the RCT design where all participants get placebo first, then non-responders get randomized to treatment?

Tags: experiment-design, control-group

I'm trying to find a paper documenting an RCT design where all participants start by receiving the placebo only, and then participants who do not respond to the placebo get randomized to treatment/control (control = continuing with the placebo). The idea is that the study can estimate the effect of treatment on people who would not benefit from the placebo. Does anybody have a citation for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of a run-in period! https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6377048/